# Facebook authentication redirection loop

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to add the ability to share the product that you just purchased to my website using the [Facebook C# SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk). To do this you need to authenticate the user with Facebook and get the required permissions.

I've got some code which checks if you're authenticated, if not, redirects you to the Facebook oAuth page to authenticate.

However, when the page returns from Facebook, it goes into a redirect loop:

```
var auth = new FacebookWebAuthorizer();

bool authorized = auth.FacebookWebRequest.IsAuthorized(new string[] { "publish_stream" });

if (authorized)
{

    var client = new FacebookClient(auth.FacebookWebRequest.AccessToken);

    Dictionary<string, object> args = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    args["message"] = "This is a test.";
    args["name"] = "";
    args["link"] = "http://www.example.com/";
    args["description"] = "Test link.";

    client.Post("/me/feed", args);

}
else
{

    var facebookClient = new FacebookOAuthClient();

    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "redirect_uri", "http://www.example.com/" },
        { "client_id", "xxxx" },
        { "scope", "publish_stream" }
    };

    Response.Redirect(facebookClient.GetLoginUrl(parameters).ToString(), true);

}
```

My web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <section name="facebookSettings" type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection" />
    </configSections>

    <system.web>

        <customErrors mode="Off" />

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>

        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />

        <handlers>
            <add name="facebookredirect.axd" verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" />
        </handlers>

    </system.webServer>

    <facebookSettings appId="xxxx" appSecret="xxxx" />

</configuration>
```

It looks like my site isn't recognising that I'm already authenticated, so it redirects to the Facebook login. Facebook then knows that I'm authenticated, so it redirects me back, causing the loop.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't offer a solution, just a description of the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Loops like this are generally caused by a browser not liking to accept the thirdparty cookie.  Try setting a P3P header in your webserver's response.  See: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx for more information.  Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I developed some sample code available at http://aka.ms/need01 that doesn't use cookies at all. Basically, it uses a custom Authentication module I wrote (with session state stored in Windows Azure tables, but you can write one that uses another store) and stores the rest of its state in the URL.
Hope this helps