# Invalid access token

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-authentication

I am having an issue since two days ago. In some of my applications -which previously were working with no problem-, I have an infinite loop (after authenticating user). It is not a persistent issue and sometimes comes and then goes by itself (without me even touch the application). Also it is not for everybody (at the same time that I cannot login to my application, my wife -with her id on my computer- can login with no issue)
I thought that it could be because of some settings in applications, but I try almost all combinations with no result :(

When I debug the application I can see that the loop is because the access token I get from Facebook is invalid (expired) and my application tries to get a new one from Facebook and again the new one is invalid as well...The error message is

OAuthException: Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error.

```
auth = New CanvasAuthorizer(aa) With {
.Permissions = New String() {
"publish_stream", "user_photos", "email"
}
}
```

> and if it fail to be authorize (our case) I redirect them with

`auth.HandleUnauthorizedRequest()`

Comment: can you edit in the code you are using for auth, eg: facebook javascript sdk code?

Comment: I had a similar issue with JS sdk, to fix the issue i created a login page, where if i detect issue with user login or token i redirect user to the login page where they use js sdk login button to reauth and then provide a link to continue.  "to the page they where redirected from"

Comment: can you edit in the actual block of code you are using for the auth?

Comment: Refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309147/facebook-authentication-redirection-loop  This may be related.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is because of a bug. In my case it got worst and no connections could be made to facebook for a few hours. But now both of them has been resolved. Related bugs are
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/179301482177807?browse=search_4fd8b6bc806f30603159377
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/367369176650486?browse=search_4fd8b7298e1870748624294